# Pandas read_excel() parses date columns with blank values to NaT

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read an excel file that has date columns with the below code

```
src1_df = pd.read_excel("src_file1.xlsx", keep_default_na = False)
```

Even though I have specified, keep_default_na = False, I see that the data frame has 'NaT' value(s) for corresponding blank cells in Excel date columns.

Please suggest, how to get a blank string instead of 'NaT' while parsing Excel files.

I am using Python 3.x and Pandas 0.23.4

Comment: You shouldn't have blank strings. Your columns type will be `date time`, and blank date times are `NaT`s. This yields some optimization form behind the scenes. IF you substitute these values for empty strings, you'll have a `object` series instead, which may decrease performance significantly

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But I need to read the blank date/time values in excel to empty strings in the dataframe. It is all right to have the type of that column be str or object.

Comment: can just `df.fillna('')`

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing as a post data read step. Was wondering if this can be done as a part of read_excel() method.    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
src1_df = pd.read_excel("src_file1.xlsx", na_filter=False)
```

Then you will have empty string ("") as "na" value

In my case I read excel per line and replace "" and "NaT" to None:

```
for line in src1_df.values:
    for index, value in enumerate(line):
        if value == '' or isinstance(value, pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType):
            line[index] = None
dostuff_with(line)
```